# Let $M_{m×n}(\Bbb R)$ be the set of all $m×n$ matrices with real entries. Then $A \in M_{2×5}(\Bbb R)$ and $B \in M_{5×2}(\Bbb R)$ s.t. $AB = I$

Tags: matrices

Let $M_{m×n}(\Bbb R)$ be the set of all $m×n$ matrices with real entries. Prove that there exist $A \in M_{2×5}(\Bbb R)$ and  $B \in M_{5×2}(\Bbb R)$ such that $AB$ is the $2×2$ identity matrix.

My attempt:

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}&a_{15}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}&a_{25}\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\\b_{31}&b_{32}\\b_{41}&b_{42}\\b_{51}&b_{52}\end{pmatrix}$. Let $C = \begin{pmatrix} c_{11}&c_{12}\\c_{21}&c_{22}\end{pmatrix} =AB$. But $C \neq I$ in general. Please help me.

Comment: Set the first row of $A$ to be $1,0,0,0,0$, as well as the first column of $B$. Do something similar with the second row of $A$ and the second column of $B$.

Comment: This is one of the cases when there is too much noise. Consider only the matrices A with $a_{13} = a_{14} = a_{15} = 0$ and $a_{23} = a_{24} = a_{25}= 0$, and the matrices $B$ with $b_{31} = b_{41} = b_{51} = 0$ and $b_{32} = b_{42} = b_{52} = 0$. See how these simplified matrices multiply.